# How should I treat Frangipani rust?

Tags: plant-health, diseases, rust

**My frangipani experiences rust. How should I best treat/protect my plant from rust (all year round)?**

My plant experienced severe rust during December/January (Australian Summer). It was a very wet and a very cool summer for Australia (record rain days).

It is two years old and last year I cut the stems to encourage shape. I don't plant to cut the stems this winter as I am looking forward to my first flowers.

During summer and in particular during the bad January, I used a copper spray with pest oil. It did not seem to help. I also sprayed the ground around the plant.

When leaves are very rusty, I removed them. I also remove fallen leaves and place them in the bin.

My plant is in a well drained full sun position (Sydney climate). The soil has sand mixed through, coal ash (from my Weber BBQ) and is in a raised bed. It cannot flood in its position.

Oddly, (April), the remaining leaves show no more severe rust. You can see some signs on close inspection. So it appears healthy now. We are moving into winter and the plant will drop its leaves soon.

I have seen comments on the interweb stating that rust is a result of the plant missing some essential elements.

Here is a comment i found:
From - http://aussieorganicgardening.com/?p=146

```
Rust is a sign that the trees are lacking trace elements. Add a twice annual drink of seaweed 
extract tea to the soil. If the infestation is severe also spray them with chamomile tea
 (you can make it up using tea bags).
```

I have also seen this product: http://frangipanirust.com.au/

Answer (score 4):

The Yates rose gun seems to get rid of rust on frangipanis. I have had some good results in Broome and Melbourne using this product.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the product and a little bit more information on the procedure/what it does/how it works?